# Changing the database in app configuration doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6, config

I have created my c# application using entity framework. The app config generated when creating data model looks like following. I want to change the name of the database and run application with a different database by running all the query changes I made when making the application. I created a new database with a different name and added all the query changes to it. And when I run the application it shows that table names doesn't exist though they exist already in the database.

My app config looks like this.
the changed config line with new database name is in the comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RIT_Allocation_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataControllers.JobAllocationDataModel.csdl|res://*/DataControllers.JobAllocationDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataControllers.JobAllocationDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=.;initial catalog=&quot;RIT_POS_DB ALUTECH HO 12112018&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   <!-- <add name="RIT_Allocation_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataControllers.JobAllocationDataModel.csdl|res://*/DataControllers.JobAllocationDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataControllers.JobAllocationDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=.;initial catalog=&quot;RIT_POS_DATABASE&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

How to change my database and add the table changes to it and run my application? Or do I need to change the database name somewhere else in the application?

I'm working with one project creating the application.

Comment: Are you working with one or multiple projects?

Comment: @MindSwipe I'm working with one project.

Comment: *data source=.;* Is this really like this?

Comment: At the "catalog=&quot;RIT_POS_DB ALUTECH..." you have multiple spaces, is this intended?

Comment: @MindSwipe the database name contains spaces.

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow didnt get you. it works fine.

Comment: Try renaming the database so it doesn't contain spaces or try escaping the database name with single quotes, like this `'RIT_POS_DB ALUTECH...'`

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow `data source=.;` is shorthand for `data source=localhost;` as the `.` just means here, or local

Comment: @MindSwipe the database name with spaces works fine. What is not working is the commented line ..

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow yes it is local

Comment: @MindSwipe Following error occurs when I add single quotes in the connection string. Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 195.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184983/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-chathwind).

Comment: @MindSwipe thank you. I found the solution. I have used a wrong database name. Now it connects fine and works fine.